# What do the paintings in Charles Lee Ray's apartment represent?

Tags: childs-play

In the original *Child's Play* from 1988, the serial killer Charles Lee Ray transfers his soul into the doll Chucky. After investigating a series of suspicious deaths, detective Mike Norris goes to Ray's apartment. On its walls are an assortment of paintings, one of which is of him bowing at the feet of his voodoo doctor, John. There are plenty of more around the apartment and I was just wondering if there is any information about what they are supposed to represent. Is it supposed to have to do with his desire to cheat death? If so, are they simply original creations of the production designer or based on real-life imagery?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In the movie scene, the camera pans from right to left telling the story of Charles Lee Ray's "plans" to cheat death. He begs for the secrets of voudou from John on the right, and the figure of John points with a knife to the voudou veve symbol in white that invokes the Loa (god) Damballa. Then there's Charles offering his own blood as well as male and female murder victims as payment for immortality from Damballa. On the far left the pictures of Charles are no longer kneeling but he is standing, after gaining immortality (or "Life after death" as written on the wall) and he's standing over more victims, or maybe they are his own corpse and soul he is standing over as an immortal.

I'm guessing that he made it as far as the second picture in his plan before he was shot and forced to transfer his essence into a doll, but he had already gained enough power from enough victims to call on Damballa and transfer his soul into other objects. Damballa is like the god of cosmic balance, so whatever Charles did, he used blood and innocents to pervert the natural order and persuade Damballa to grant him more life.